# Math mode space after id

Tags: math-mode

I need to write *idb* in math mode. But a space appears after *id* and I get *id b*.
How can I remove this space?

Code example:

```
$idb$
```

Comment: there will be no space! Create a complete example which shows this behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does *idb* denote a single object or the multiplication “*i* times *d* times *b*”? However, this is what I get from `$idb$`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IFAid.png There is no strange space, so it's necessary you give some more information.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggest `idb` here is meant to be a three-character variable. If this is the case you can write it in math mode as follows:

`$\mathit{idb}$`

Then you get the correct spacing because LaTex assumes `idb` is just `i` times `db` here and `db` is treated as a differential term.

If you mean the multiplication just write it as follows:

`$idb$`

An image is provided for the first (upper) and the second (lower) approach.

[image]